# Why didn't the Cylons just build a new resurrection hub?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

In the reimagined *Battlestar Galactica* season 4, a plan to destroy the Cylon resurrection hub is hatched. The humans seem to think that this will prevent all Cylons resurrecting forever.

Why would they assume that and why would it be true? Couldn't the Cylons just build a new one? Didn't they build the first one?

Answer (score 4):

The hub was created by the "Final Five", although the Cylons know how to use and operate the technology they lacked the knowledge to replicate the technology. Seeing The Final Five lost their memories they would be unable to help (and probably unwilling as well) build a new one.

The technology was original created by the Original AI's on Earth, but after they eventually started to reproduce naturally the technology became obsolete and lost. But the five were researching a re-invention of the technology. Eventually it was this that spared them from the Holocaust that happened on the original earth, seeing they got resurrected.

Each one of them knew only a part of the entire process so all 5 of them would be essential in recreating the technology (it would probably be possible with fewer, yet each member lost would significantly increase the required research period).

The Five offer to give back Resurrection if they agree to leave humanity alone forever. They combine the keys to Resurrection technology in their minds and start transmitting to the Colony, but a side-effect is that they see each other's memories at the same time. This leads to a conflict between them about past actions , breaking the Five's download to the Colony and killing one of them.

Later, the people of the Fleet have one of the five fly Galactica and the other ships into the Sun, destroying the ships and himself. With the deaths of these 2 out of 5, there are only three of the Final Five left alive making it near impossible to replicate the technology.

The most inportant scene that shows this is the one where they strike a deal with Cylon #1 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVKhryKnmtc&ab_channel=BattlestarGalactica). It is clear from this scene alone that the Cylons needed help from the Five to rebuild the technology, something they were willing to give in exchange for peace. (This happens during the final moments of the Cylon/human conflict where Cylon #1 takes a hostage on the Galactica bridge.)

Source episodes about the 5 being the ones that build the resurrection hub: "No Exit", "Daybreak, Part I", "Daybreak, Part II"

Comment: Until they regain their memories in S4. The Cylons strike a truce with the humans to let them go with the child in return for the FF giving them Resurrection tech again.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan still the Cylons could not build one themselves, an shortly after the destruction of the hub, 2 of the 5 died. Seeing each held only partial knowledge of the hub creation process the technology would still be lost.

Comment: Can you back up these bold statements with any evidence?

Comment: @A.bakker True, but at that point the whole thing was moot. Both sides knew resurrection was out of reach as Tory was now dead. Sam was a tub hybrid after extensive brain damage but not dead. I’m just talking about before things fell apart in the CIC, they all five had started to upload to the Cylons when Chief discovered Tory’s deceptions and murder of his wife.

Comment: @Valorum i linked the episodes in which the hub tech was mentioned, including the fact that only the 5 were able to create it.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan yea i edited my answer but i kept out the names of The Five for potential spoilers for people who don't know the identities yet.

Comment: That's better, but simply pointing at an entire episode is pretty lazy sourcing. Can you identify the scene/dialogue that confirms your points?

Comment: @Valorum done, had to look it up seeing i last saw this series over 4 years ago (well actually started re-watching this month, but not this far yet)

Comment: "...making it near impossible to replicate the technology." Because something that has been invented once cannot be reinvented in a fictional universe stressing the repetition of historical cycles? Do you mean "within a short period of time which would affect the outcome of the current war?"

Comment: @Lexible near impossible as in not in the given time frame, in season 4 it was mentioned that humanoid cylons will die of old age. And let's not forget, we in real life still got some question marks in things made a long time ago. Eventually they would have found a way if they did not go extinct beforehand due to lack of retrodictive solutions and resurrection technology.

Comment: I do not think that the interpretation in your last comment is supported in universe.